# Time-series Forecasting model for License monitoring

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression

I am trying to build a forecasting model to predict the number of  used licenses for an application-feature combination in the future.

The data (time-series data) in which at a point in time, the 'used' number of licenses of several applications and their corresponding features are observed. So the data would look sometime like (Timestamp, application, Feature and used).

What would be a possible model to use in this case as the measurements of the value 'used' can be spoardic and is done only when the value of 'used' of that particular application/feature combination changes.

Since there might be several application/featurecombinations, do I need a separate model for each of the unique combination ? By that, I mean that there are no continous measurements of the value 'used' for each combination of application and feature.

I tried a random forest regression model just directly feeding the data without aggregations or grouping based on application and features. I mean I used all the data consisting of information for all application and feature combinations. This model currently has a low variance problem. I want to try out a window based prediction using LSTM. But here the confusion arises if I have to build separate models for each application and feature combination

Comment: What have you tried so far? What models have you used or considered?

Comment: I tried a random forest regression model just directly feeding the data without aggregations or grouping based on application and features. I mean I used all the data consisting of information for all application and feature combinations. This model currently has a low variance problem. 

I want to try out a window  based prediction using LSTM. But here the confusion arises  if I have to build separate models for each application and feature combination.

Comment: Can you please update your question so that it includes this information? Please try to give more focus to your question, because right now, I find it very difficult to know where to start with answering it

Comment: Thanks for your messgae. I have slightly rephrased the question. If it is still not clear, please let me know I will completely reqrite the question.